# What are the "N" versions of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, msdn

Microsoft just released the final Windows 8 versions for MSDN members, before its consumer release in october.

Anyway, I am a MSDN member. Today I went to see my downloads page and I found a list of the new versions to be downloaded.

- Windows 8
- Windows 8 N
- Windows 8 Pro
- Windows 8 Pro N
- Windows 8 Enterprise
- Windows 8 Enterprise N

I know the difference between the  versions "**Windows 8**", "**Windows 8 Pro**" and "**Windows 8 Enterprise**", which you easily find at wikipedia.

But, I really need to know the difference between these versions and the "N" versions before download one of them.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Wikipedia also explains N versions, look under ["Special-purpose editions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Special-purpose_editions) in the Windows 7 Wiki.

> #### N and KN editions
>
> The features in the N and KN Editions are the same as their equivalent full versions, but do not include Windows Media Player or other Windows Media-related technologies, such as Windows Media Center and Windows DVD Maker. The cost of the N and KN Editions are the same as the full versions, as the Media Feature Pack for Windows 7 N or Windows 7 KN can be downloaded without charge from Microsoft.

N versions were created due to a fine/settlement with the [European Union](http://crave.cnet.co.uk/software/windows-7-n-the-n-editions-explained-49303415/)

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the Wikipedia page for Windows 8, too.