# What's the difference between Windows 8 N (x64) - DVD (English) and Windows 8 (x64) - DVD (English)

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, msdn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Versions (Final Release)](https://superuser.com/questions/462203/windows-8-versions-final-release)

Windows 8 got released on MSDN 15/8.

I have a subscription to MSDN thru work and wanted to download it. But for each windows 8 there are 2 editions, one have the appending "N".

Is this a language indication? N for "norwegian" maybe? (my MSDN and myself are norwegian)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Windows 7 N

Fast-forward to today, and a Microsoft spokesperson explained to CNET UK, "The European Commission's 2004 decision requires Microsoft to offer an N version of Windows in Europe. We continue to abide by this ruling."

And so Windows 7 N was born. They cost the same as their non-'N' brothers and sisters, and apart from Windows Media Player, offer the same spread of features.

All you have to do now is decide which of the six non-N versions are right for you, and, wouldn't you know it, we have a handy, simple guide for that as well,"

[Source](http://crave.cnet.co.uk/software/windows-7-n-the-n-editions-explained-49303415/)

Answer (score 2):

No, "N" editions are released in Europe and don't contain Media Player. Beside the lack of a Windows Media Player, there is no other difference.