# What is "Windows 8 N" and how is it different from "Windows 8"?

Tags: windows-8, msdn, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the “N” versions of Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462203/windows-8-versions-final-release)

I have an MSDN account and one thing I noticed is that there seems to be 2 different versions of Windows 8.

For instance, there is:

- Windows 8 (x86/x64)
- Winodws 8 Enterprise (x86/x64)
- Windows 8 Debug/Checked (x86/x64)

and then there is also

- Windows 8 N (x86/x64)
- Winodws 8 Enterprise N (x86/x64)
- Windows 8 Debug/Checked N (x86/x64)

What exactly does the "N" mean? I've searched on the internet to try to figure out what the difference is, but I can't find any reference that the N images even exist!

Does anyone know what they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that they're using the same nomenclature as for [Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/What-is-Windows-7-N-edition)

> The N editions of Windows 7 allow you to choose your own media player and software required to manage and play CDs, DVDs, and other digital media files.

Basically it's the version the EU requires Microsoft to sell so people can pick their own media player and not have Windows Media Player "forced" on them.

Answer (score 11):

> The N edition is for the European market. It comes without Windows Media Player. It is the result of a European lawsuit against Microsoft for bundling non-essential apps into the OS.

http://www.forumswindows8.com/general-discussion/what-windows-8-n-edition-7500.htm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8 search for "Euro" also confirms this.

Answer (score 2):

Its a special regional copy of Windows 8 sold in certain regions.  Windows 7 has a similar edition with certain features that were determined illegal ( because it was intergrated with the operating system ) in those regions.

One of the main differences is the lack of Windows Media Player.